# Traffic shaping for multipath routing in OVS

Tags: traffic-shaping, multipath, openvswitch

I'm working with OVS and tried multipath routing using group tables like in this link: https://github.com/PSIB0T/Multipath-Routing. It splits traffic to buckets with output is different ports.

At first, I thought the traffic would be split into buckets proportional to the weights, then I realized that the traffic mostly goes through the path with the highest weight, other paths don't have any traffic. I found it's caused by the way group table work (hashing). But if so, it means to pass traffic along multiple paths will be no different than passing traffic along the highest weight path. I have an idea about traffic shaping for each path. I tried combining group table with OVS queue to shape traffic for each path, but it didn't work. I am stuck at that stage; can anyone give me some suggestions to implement the above idea?